# Reputation discrepancy

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I know we shouldn't really be too worried about reputation but I was curious as to why there is a discrepancy between the reputation listed in the user profile for many members (not all) and the reputation in the Users list. In my case I currently have a 410 rep in my profile but the Users list it't listed as 299.

Comment: There are also discrepancies on the area51 page where it lists the most active users, which is super confusing.

Answer (score 4):

When looking at the user list the list is there's a filter on the right side. By default it filters to "quarter", at least for me it does. If you select "all" you'll see your correct rep. I've also noticed that the main site and meta site have a slight delay in sync.

[image: user list]

Comment: Why would there still be a difference for some users when you select year or quarter? EESE has not been around long enough where there should be a difference with these options.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know for sure, but I think this is basically just due to caching on SX's part.

Though rep changes frequently, there are such a large number of factors that influence it (ie votes across all qns, answers, comments, edits etc) that it makes sense to cache it given that as you say it's not a huge deal if it's out a bit.

It looks to me like they cache rep/badges for views where there are multiple users shown, but if you click through you get the non-cached score (as you definitely want to see correct data for that user and it's less computationally expensive for them to do so than when showing 50 users at once).

Give it an hour or so and it'll probably even up (unless you get more rep in the meantime of course).

Comment: This is it. The rep leagues are cached for some time (I'm not sure how long off the top of my head). User profiles should be accurate to within 5 minutes or so, so you can treat that as the "master" number.